# GUID for linux and windows application, Qt

Tags: windows, linux, qt, guid

I'm using Qt 4.x to develop a portable applicaion that will run on linux and windows. I want to add to the application an identifier such like a guid. how can I do that? what is the connection in the application I have to do the the id? and GUID - is it only for windows? (I want something that will be for both linux and windows)

10x!

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. If you aren't sure what the GUID will be used for, why do you want to generate one?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if I understand your question(s) correctly, but I think [QUuid](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/quuid.html) ([qt5 link here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html)) is what you're looking for. It generates UUIDs (which GUIDs seem to be a special case of) for all supported platforms.

Comment: Note that `QUuid` will generate GUIDs on Windows.

Comment: Updated with Digia links.